# Too much 'Tik-tik' noise from Rocker box after driving 10-15 km from cold engine condition in my classic 350

Tags: motorcycle, noise, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

My bike is driven 15000 kms and rocker box started noise problem since 8000 to 9000 kms.
Even oil and oil filter is changed today but problem of noise is still going on.
Can be rocker box adjusted? Or what can be done ?

Comment: Does the noise disappear above 3500 rpm?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  ya at high rpm noise dissappears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your Valve Lash Requires Adjustment**

Valve lash is the distance between your valve stem and, in your case, the rocker arm.  You have a camshaft inside your engine case or 'bottom end'.  The reciprocating actuation is transferred to the top end via a push rod which contacts the rocker arm which actuates your valves.

Increased valve lash over time is a normal event and is a part of normal maintenance of your vehicle.  Over time, as your engine wears in, and valve lash increases.  The sound is a repetitive ticking noise that matches the RPMs of your engine.  It can be a bit loud and annoying but it isn't a critical event.  You do need to get it adjusted or do it yourself though, if not, it will continue to wear and possibly damage your engine.

Valve lash can be adjusted by removing the rocker box cover to reveal a threaded shaft and a lock not adjust shaft length.

[**Here is some additional information**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/16716/9164) regarding your valve tick.

Answer (score 0):

What you are most likely hearing is the Auto Decompressor which is used on the newer (2010+) Royal Enfield bike engines. It is used to automatically release the pressure in the bike for when you go to start it. Without it, there is the possibility of a kick-back on the engine when trying to start, which could cause damage to the engine/bike and/or the rider.

You can take it to a RE mechanic for adjustment, but other than the annoying noise, there shouldn't be an issue with what's going on.

Comment: Noise is coming from Rocker arms because once i opened head of bike engine to check if something can be done by me but didn't done anything because i don't have that much knowledge about internal parts and settings

Comment: Since the Auto Decompressor runs off the cam and gearing, the noise would come from the rocker arm area of the engine.

Comment: But before few thousand kms that noise wasn't  there. Thats why i am doubting about rocker arms

Comment: Like I said, you could possibly take it in for an adjustment. From what I've read, this isn't something the average person would be able to do (as you figured out when taking the rocker cover off). If you don't like the noise, take it to a mechanic to see if it can be quieted. If you don't want to take it to a mechanic, you'll just have to live with the noise. If you do leave it alone, there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: going to mechanic would be better option for me. Will post after some peroid of time about it.

Comment: can i apply greese on rocker arm ?